# Add textview right above Keyboard

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

At the moment my app consists from a `EditText` and a button, both at the bottom of the screen. If I'm typing something into the `EditText` and than hit that button a `TextView` gets created at the top of the screen.

But, what I want to achieve is that if I hit that button, that the `TextView` gets created right above the `EditText` field. And if I do that again I want the second `TextView` again created right above the `EditText` but below the other `TextView`.

This is my code so far.

Here's the xml: (This is all inside a `RelativeLayout`. But for some reason I can't put that in here because its not detected as code...)

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>


<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:text="Senden"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="470px"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

And my Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button button;
private EditText editText;
private LinearLayout linearLayout;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    final View.OnClickListener btnHandler = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String msg = editText.getText().toString();
            editText.getText().clear();
            linearLayout.addView(createNewTextView(msg));
            View view = getCurrentFocus();
            if(view != null) {
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
            }
        }
    };

    button.setOnClickListener(btnHandler);
}

private TextView createNewTextView(String text) {
    final LinearLayout.LayoutParams lparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    final TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setLayoutParams(lparams);
    textView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    textView.setText(text);

    return textView;
}
```

What do I need to change so that it appears like i want it to?

Answer (score 1):

Use `LinearLayout` as parent view with 
`android:gravity="center|bottom"` this property.

Now while adding textviews, insert newly created text view with position.

```
parentLinearLayout.addView(childtextview, index); //index represents it position in linearlayout,according to you index is always 2.
```

Comment: When you say use LinearLayout as parent view, do you mean i should replace the RelativLayout with the LinearLayout and put the edittext and the button inside it?

Comment: yes absolutely, Edittext and Button will take first two index's from bottom,so everytime you insert your textview set index as 3

Comment: So I guess i have to say too: linearLayout.addView(button, 1) and linearLayout.addView(edittext, 1). Because no my Button is at the top and the edttext is at the bottom

Comment: 1 is bottom most position,2 is above that and so on

Comment: Yeah I get that. But how do I tell it now that I want the edttext and the button at the bottom?

Comment: Place a `linearlayout` inside you `relativelayout` just above Edit Text and Button  and add textviews to that.

Comment: But then I have what I had at the start + the android:gravity property inside the linearlayout and that crashes

Comment: you're using both `Button` and `Edittext` at Same Level ?in that case you can wrap them both inside `LinearLayout` with `orientation:"horizontal"` and make parent layout `LinearLayout`.

Comment: Yes the button and the edittext should be placed along each other. So now  I replaced the RelativeLayout again with the LinearLayout and the Button and the Edittext are inside the Linearlayout but still only the edittext is at the bottom.

Comment: Would you mind, editting my code as you think it would work? Because I don't seem to understand what you want me to do

Answer (score 0):

There is nice control for a lot of views: [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html). Use if for handling your text views, and use [LinearLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.html#setReverseLayout(boolean)) for placing views in the bottom of container